# Erro de Sintaxe SQL na criação de FK

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou querendo adicionar uma **chave-estrangeira** na tabela **CONSULTA**
Só que o MySql informa o seguinte erro:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES medico(crm) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1' at line 9

O código SQL está esrito da seguinte forma abaixo:

```
CREATE TABLE `medico` (
  `crm` float(12) NOT NULL,
  `cpf` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dataInscricao` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bairro` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cidade` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `logradouro` varchar(90) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uf` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nomeUser` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `senhaUser` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cnpj` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`crm`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `consulta` (
  `codConsulta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `horario` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `crm` float(12) NOT NULL,
  `cpf` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `codTipoCons` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`codConsulta`),
  FOREIGN KEY `crm` REFERENCES `medico`(`crm`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Qual o Problema?

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, tente fazer a criação da tabela e depois alteração na tabela setando a FK desejada.

Ex:

```
    CREATE TABLE `cidades` ( 
    `codcidade` INT NOT NULL ,
    `descricao` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL) 
    ENGINE = innodb;

    ALTER TABLE `clientes` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_cidade` FOREIGN KEY ( `codcidade` ) REFERENCES `cidade` ( `codcidade` ) ;
```

Ref.: http://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-uma-chave-estrangeira-no-mysql/20299

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência. As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada

Answer (score 0):

Está faltando um `()` na criação da chave estrangeira. Ficaria assim:

```
FOREIGN KEY(`crm`) REFERENCES `medico`(`crm`)
```